# Show that a stopped process is uniformly integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

Suppose $(X, \mathscr{F})$ is a martingale. Show that $(X_{\tau \wedge n}, \mathscr{F})$ is a uniformly integrable for any finite stopping time $\tau$ such that $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable.

My attempt: In one of my textbooks (Resnick- probability path- section 6.5.1) it says that if a family of random variables $\{X_n\}$ is dominated by a uniformly integrable family $\{Y_n\}$ then the $\{X_n\}$ are also U.I.

Therefore, for this question I simply said that $|X_{\tau \wedge n}| \le |X_n|$ $\forall n$ and the result holds.

However, this is the solution to the problem.

[image]

Is this another way to solve this question? Or was there a mistake in my attempt.

Thanks.

Comment: $|X_{\tau \wedge n}| \le |X_n|$ $\forall n$ is very unlikely for a martingale (unless it's constant). So this isn't a solution. Whether the rest of your post is, is hard to tell, without knowing the relationship between $X_n$ and $Y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because $m:= \tau \wedge n \le n$ we cannot conclude that $X_{m} \le X_{n}$ pointwise... take for example the simple random walk, the stopping time $\tau = \inf_{n}\{|X_{n}|=a\}$ and some $n > \tau$ such that $X_{n}=0$